# Correct usage of AddressResolver interface

Tags: gridgain, ignite

I was wondering if there is an example usage of the AddressResolver interface in apache ignite.

I was trying to 'bind' my local IP addresses (e.g. 192.168.10.101) to my external IP address using the AddressResolver interface, but without luck.

When I do that the Ignite server just hangs (no output from the debug either)

My code for starting the server is:

```
TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();

TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();

ipFinder.setAddresses(ipaddresses);
spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
spi.setAddressResolver(new IotAddressResolver());
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

// Override default discovery SPI.
cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);
System.setProperty("IGNITE_QUIET", "false");

// Start Ignite node.
ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
```

My implementation for AddressResolver is:

```
public class IotAddressResolver implements AddressResolver {

    @Override
    public Collection<InetSocketAddress> getExternalAddresses(
            InetSocketAddress internalAddresses) throws IgniteCheckedException {

        String host = "XX.XX.XX.XX";


        Collection<InetSocketAddress> result = new ArrayList<InetSocketAddress>();
        result.add(new InetSocketAddress(host, internalAddresses.getPort()));
        return result;
    }

}
```

The last line of the ignite debug log is:

```
WARNING: Timed out waiting for message to be read (most probably, the reason is in long GC pauses on remote node) [curTimeout=9989]
```

I will appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more details about your deployment and what you're trying to achieve with the help of address resolver? How many physical hosts and Ignite nodes do you have? Are they located in different networks with the router between them?

Comment: In details - I have 2 server nodes deployed on a VPS, which are working correctly.

Comment: I want to use the Address Resolver in order to be able to run Ignite in client mode on my local machine, so I can run tests on the nodes which are running on the VPS. My local machine runs on a local network with only one public IP address for the whole network. I am using port forwarding in the router in order to be able to 'route' correctly the packets to my local machine.

Comment: Also in my application properties the addesses field is: ipaddresses=XX.XX.XX.XX:47501..47510, where XX.XX.XX.XX is the public address of my local network

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the best way to handle this but I managed to start igntie as local server. I am setting my local ip and port like this:

```
    System.setProperty("IGNITE_QUIET", "false");

    TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
    TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
    TcpCommunicationSpi commSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();

    // Set initial IP addresses.
    ipFinder.setAddresses(ipaddresses);

    spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);

    // Override local port.
    commSpi.setLocalPort(47501);
    commSpi.setLocalAddress("XX.XX.XX.XX");
    commSpi.setLocalPortRange(50);

    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

    // Override default communication SPI.
    cfg.setCommunicationSpi(commSpi);
    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);
    cfg.setAddressResolver(new IotAddressResolver());
    cfg.setClientMode(true);

    // Start Ignite node
    ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
```

Where XX.XX.XX.XX is my local IP address